How to Retrieve Live Solana Token Information Deployed on Raydium Using Geyser Plugin?
Hello Solana Community,
I’m currently trying to obtain live token information such as price, transactions, volumes, market cap, etc., for tokens deployed on Raydium. I understand that this can be achieved using the Solana Geyser plugin, and I want to calculate the token price from it without relying on any external APIs.
I’ve explored the Solana Geyser plugin, and I came across this public repo as a reference: solana-labs/solana-accountsdb-plugin-postgres. However, I’m not entirely sure how to customize it to retrieve the live token information I’m looking for.
Additionally, I found another reference repo: mwrites/solana-geyser-plugin-scaffold, but it didn’t provide the specific details I needed for my use case.
Here are the specific details I am looking to achieve:

Token Price: Calculation of real-time token prices from on-chain data.
Transactions: Live tracking of transactions involving the token.
Volume: Real-time trading volume of the token.
Market Cap: Calculation of the token's market capitalization based on circulating supply and price.

Questions:

How can I set up and configure the Solana Geyser plugin to start retrieving relevant data for tokens deployed on Raydium?
What are the best practices for calculating token prices and other metrics mentioned above using the raw data from the Geyser plugin?
Are there any specific resources, documentation, or examples that could guide me through this process?
How can I ensure the accuracy and real-time nature of the data retrieved and calculated?

I would appreciate detailed guidance or references to documentation that could help me understand and implement this. Any insights from those who have experience with the Geyser plugin or similar use-cases on Solana would be incredibly valuable.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
